# Linker error for functions expecting const std::string &

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, linker

When trying to link against a shared library (*gtkmm*), I get linker errors for functions whose signature contains a `std::string const&`.

For example, if the function is declared as

```cpp
void set_icon_from_file(const std::string&);
```

g++ reports

```
undefined reference to `Gtk::Window::set_icon_from_file(std::string const&)'
```

I am using the linker flags from `pkg-config`, and this does not happen for other functions (functions taking primitive types as arguments, for example), so I suspect the linker is configured properly.

`readelf` on my object file gives me

```
45: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _ZN3Gtk6Window18set_icon_from_fileERKSs
```

and on the shared library

```
10991: 00000000003c0950    96 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 _ZN3Gtk6Window18set_icon_from_fileERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
```

I'm not sure what to make of that. I checked that the functions are declared with the same signature in both the library headers and source. Because of the `__cxx11` part in the mangled name, I first suspected a compatibility issue between C++ versions, however, I'm building with C++11 as well.

Comment: There were some changes in GNU libstdc++ when C++11 was finalized. The problem might be that your gtkmm was compiled with older compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at my c++-filt output:

```
_ZN3Gtk6Window18set_icon_from_fileERKSs
Gtk::Window::set_icon_from_file(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
_ZN3Gtk6Window18set_icon_from_fileERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
Gtk::Window::set_icon_from_file(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
```

It means that the second version is compiled with glibcxx11 abi enabled.
[Here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html) more information about it.

So, basically you need to update your gcc to 5.1 version or downgrade the library.

Comment: Excellent, a simple compiler update actually fixed the problem. I also did not know about `c++filt`, handy little tool!